# Adding line to CartoDB?

Tags: carto, editing

I watched the tutorial "Create your own data using the CartoDB Editor" about adding a feature but in the editor, I couldnt seem to find the adding a line feature.

When I click the button of add feature, there were no options of add line, the default response was just to add a point

Comment: Can you give a bit more information about the tutorial, a link perhaps. You will need to indicate what software you're talking about as well.

Comment: There is an **edit** button beneath your question that you can use to revise it with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Layers in CartoDB are single-geometry at this moment, which means that you can only add a type of geometry in each layer. (Points, lines or polygons).

If I'm not wrong, the tutorial you're mentioning is adding extra layers per each kind of geometry. That's what you need to do too.

In the right toolbar, there's a '+' icon in the top which allows you to add a new layer to your map. Just add it from an empty/new table and you'll be able to start drawing geometries of other type there.

If you need to have points, lines and polygons in your map, then you'll need at least 3 layers.